# Upgrading PHP 8.1 results in a load of CLASS-WALKER-NAV-MENU.PHP errors

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I want some help regarding PHP up-gradation. Previously [my website](https://www.tutsinsider.com/) was running on PHP version 7.3 or 7.4, but lately, when I upgraded to version 8.1, it gave a lot of errors. The error mainly occurred on the search.php.

Whenever I search some string, it fills the whole page with errors. also, the admin header, page content, and footer vanish.

The errors are just like those below:

```
WARNING: IMPLODE(): INVALID ARGUMENTS PASSED IN /HOME/U274843758/DOMAINS/TUTSINSIDER.COM/PUBLIC_HTML/WP-INCLUDES/CLASS-WALKER-NAV-MENU.PHP ON LINE 158

WARNING: IMPLODE(): INVALID ARGUMENTS PASSED IN /HOME/U274843758/DOMAINS/TUTSINSIDER.COM/PUBLIC_HTML/WP-INCLUDES/CLASS-WALKER-NAV-MENU.PHP ON LINE 158

WARNING: IMPLODE(): INVALID ARGUMENTS PASSED IN /HOME/U274843758/DOMAINS/TUTSINSIDER.COM/PUBLIC_HTML/WP-INCLUDES/CLASS-WALKER-NAV-MENU.PHP ON LINE 158

WARNING: IMPLODE(): INVALID ARGUMENTS PASSED IN /HOME/U274843758/DOMAINS/TUTSINSIDER.COM/PUBLIC_HTML/WP-INCLUDES/CLASS-WALKER-NAV-MENU.PHP ON LINE 158

WARNING: IMPLODE(): INVALID ARGUMENTS PASSED IN /HOME/U274843758/DOMAINS/TUTSINSIDER.COM/PUBLIC_HTML/WP-INCLUDES/CLASS-WALKER-NAV-MENU.PHP ON LINE 158

WARNING: IMPLODE(): INVALID ARGUMENTS PASSED IN /HOME/U274843758/DOMAINS/TUTSINSIDER.COM/PUBLIC_HTML/WP-INCLUDES/CLASS-WALKER-NAV-MENU.PHP ON LINE
```

Also, when I navigated to the **wp_nav_menu()** function in my theme and removed it, the search page worked fine. Further, when I navigated to the **class-walker-nav-menu.php file** and removed the specifically mentioned line, the page worked just fine.
kindly help me if anybody knows about the problem.

Also, i am using the below code to generate my site navigation.

```
wp_nav_menu( 
  array(
    'menu'              => 'footer-menu', 
    'theme_location'    => 'footer_menu', 
    'menu_id'           => 'footerMenu', 
    'fallback_cb'       => 'false', 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Is that the whole list of errors? I suspect that your version of Wordpress uses some deprecated function. Did you check for compatibility before upgrading PHP?

Comment: I didn't, how to check compatibility and deprecated funcitons?

Comment: @kissumisa , kindly help me if you can. I am currently running PHP v7.4 again. Updating to v8.1 or 8.0 turns out to be disastrous for the search page.